# Flutter access State<T> from it's StatefulWidget

Tags: flutter, flutter-state

I'm writing a Application, where Widgets and their State need to be saved to Disk and later be restored. In order to save a `StatefulWidget`  I need to access it's corresponding `State<T>` object.

Here's how I imagined the code to look like:

```
class Block extends StatefulWidget {
  const Block({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  void saveToDisk(){
    // access BlockState object
    // save to disk…
  }

  @override
  BlockState createState() => BlockState();
}

class BlockState extends State<Block> {
  final String _someState = ‚Hello Stackoverflow‘;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const Text(‚Some Text‘);
  }
}
```

Does anybody know how to access the `BlockState` object (first comment in `saveToDisk()`)?

Comment: most likely you need [RestorationMixin](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/RestorationMixin-mixin.html) mixin - the docs say: *"Manages the restoration data for a State object of a StatefulWidget.

Restoration data can be serialized out and, at a later point in time, be used to restore the stateful members in the State object to the same values they had when the data was generated."*

Comment: @pskink thanks a lot! This looks like what I was looking for.

Comment: sure, your welcome

Answer (score 0):

widget.saveToDisk();

All stateful widgets have it this way.